# Check health of internet connection over undetermined period of time

Tags: bash, networking, ping

Disconnection based on certain factors can happen, and since I don't always or can't always use Ethernet(since I'm using wifi), i thought of checking when or at least *how much* i get disconnected from Internet in an undetermined amount of time.

I mostly want to know that since i need to stay connected, and knowing when it is disconnected without looking at which moment a process/job stopped/failed is a bit more helpful.

So i tried using ping as a basis:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
retryme() {
while ! "$@"
do
  echo "not_working -> $(date)"
done
}

retryme ping google.com
```

Problem is, there a slight latency of 6-5 seconds between `ping` actually starting and `ping` actually pinging...(although it is alleviated by about 1 second or so if i use the `-A` flag)

Beside that, it also doesn't really show output only when it disconnect (which is the wanted effect), unless i do this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -x
retryme() {
while ! "$@"
do
  echo "not_working -> $(date)"
done
}

pingme() {
ping -A google.com &>/dev/null
}

retryme pingme
```

But then it kind of hang when Internet disconnect and doesn't "retry" using the retry function...

Is there a better way to do this? maybe with something else than ping (preferably using POSIX or bash, and/or other linux tools)

Comment: Regarding the delay when you start ping, this is probably due to the DNS lookup. It won't happen when you use an IP address such as 1.1.1.1. Regarding the apparent hang when the connection is interrupted, you could try setting a timeout with `ping -W`. Regarding alternatives, you can use a higher level protocol such as `dig -t soa @1.1.1.1` or `curl google.com`. Not sure if these commands have timeout parameters. A random internet search yielded this page with interesting ideas: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/commands-check-if-connected-to-internet-shell. I'd avoid `nmap`, though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment! Didn't thought of using `dig` (mostly because it's not on every distro). I'm used to `curl` and know the `timeout` flag from experience, didn't thought of this. Will try and report back :) @berndbausch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this works:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
retryme() {
while ! "$@"
do
  echo "not_working -> $(date)"
done
}

pingme() {
ping -A -W 1 8.8.8.8 &>/dev/null
}

retryme pingme
```